# import time stamps matlab

Tags: matlab, time, xlsx

I have a xlsx file containing time stamps in the format [mm:ss] 
for example

```
00:01
00:04
00:07
00:10
00:12
```

I would like to import it in Matlab, but when I use
`xlsread('namefile.xlsx')` it converts the content of the column.

ps I run Matlab on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is a representation of the time as a single value. Luckily, for times there is no difference between excel and matlab, both use fractions of a full day. (while for dates there is a different "zero")

To get back minutes:seconds use:

```
datestr(a,'MM:SS')
```

Please note that `MM` is minutes while `mm` is month, this is a common cause for errors.